# while appending data in mysql '+' symbol is removed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql through PHP+AJAX. My ajax string has

```
http://a.d.b.c/cb/login/insertMegaScore.php?user_id=CBS_00002&package_id=d47kndffqc&mega_level=3&timestring=2017-04-08T11:57:56+05:30
```

The string has **timestring=2017-04-08T11:57:56+05:30**. But when inserted in mysql, the '**+**' symbol is removed and i see **2017-04-08T11:57:56 05:30**.

Can anyone please help me understand, why '+' is being removed. My sql structure is `timestring varchar(30) utf8_unicode_ci`

and my php is very simple, `$timestring = $_REQUEST['timestring'];`

Answer (score 0):

the `+`  is used as special character in URL request  then you should use  proper URL encoding

```
 +  =   %2B
```

.

```
 2017-04-08T11:57:56%2B05:30
```

for this you should use `urlencode( $yourUlr )`  and `urldecode( $youEncodedUrl )`

if you have already encoded  use urldecode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I triedthis , but now mysql has literal 2017-04-08T11:57:56%2B05:30, as field, rather than having '+' sign

Comment: answer  updated ... you must use urlDecode cof get the + sign